# htaccess multiple top level domains and http to https with www

Tags: .htaccess

I know the question is simple but I simply can not find it - so: I need to redirect all requested URIs to multiple top level domains, with or without www, with https or http to one single top level domain with https and www.

For example:

```
http://example.com
http://www.example.com
https://example.com
https://www.example.com
http://example.de
http://www.example.de
https://example.de
```

TO:

```
https://www.example.de
```

What does the correct rewrite block look like?

Answer (score 0):

You may use this single rule for all these use-cases in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

## add www and turn on https in same rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.de$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.de%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Oops.. I didn't see this. Deleting my answer now. +1 :)

Comment: Nice! But I changed the RewriteRule as follows: `^(.*)$ https://www.example.de/$1 [NE,L,R=301]` ...not sure what `^(.*)$` (regEx?) does and how `$1` works

Comment: Well. The RewriteRule didn't work. It has a little mistake in "http:/www" (single slash)

Comment: oh that was a typo and I have fixed it. Now tell me what URL did you enter in browser and what error did you get. Make sure this is the **top most** run in your .htaccess and you test from a new browser.

Comment: And this assumes that DocumentRoot of all the domains is same directory path on same host.